# Spring HttpHeaders - get Authorization header

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

How do I retrieve `Authorization` header from `HttpHeaders`? there is no matching method like the rest of the headers.
I manged to get it like -

```
HttpHeaders headers = sendPost.getHeaders();
List<String> list = headers.get(JwtFilterLogin.HEADER_AUTH); //header key - Authorization
System.out.println(list.get(0)); //the value
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Your "get first value" logic is already provided by `HttpHeaders#getFirst()` . Furthermore , `Authorization` header field name is also provided by `HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION` such that you do not need to define by your own :

```
HttpHeaders headers = sendPost.getHeaders();
String value = headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```